# I need a box like gmail chat which doesnt load with the page

Tags: jquery, chat

I really appreciate the way you answered my questions, and I have one more question. Thanks in advance for your time.

I am planning to have a box somewhere on the page, and that should not be loaded with  the pages of my website. It should be closed only when I close the website,  similar to the chat box in gmail. As other pages are loaded, the chat box at the botton right corner stays same. Please give me some guidance.

I have looked at google as an example. Where should I start. My initial plan is to make a div stick at the bottom and z-index it to make it float over the page at the right bottom corner. But when I click on the other link, the page loads the div which I have fixed at the bottom is loading . So can you please help me?

I would like to add a radio type div on my site with no interruption while they are navigating the pages. I am using a streaming service.

Comment: You should first plan to try writing some code and do some research yourself and post your attempt(s) here.

Comment: what was your **question** again? Oh wait, you want a software developed??

Comment: He is asking how google is doing this and asking for some pointers. I think it's a legit question for a beginner. No need to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

what google, etc. are doing is, when you click on a link instead of changing the page, they just load the new content from the server in the background and then replacing the content of the current page with the new content (except for the chat window of course). Like this it feels like you are navigating to another page, but really you are only exchanging the content of the current one.

There are a lot of techniques to make this "invisible" to the user. In general this is called AJAX. Read up on it!

Good luck!